# Help with understanding Induction proofs

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

From my understanding, to prove induction problems, we must:

- Find a base case
- Assume n=k holds true
- Prove n=k+1 with the assumption

However I am looking at the proof of a problem and they don't seem to use this method.

[image]

Solution

[image]

Did they not just use a direct proof? How is induction used in this solution?

Any help or advice would be great!

Comment: They used the inductive hypothesis (the assumption that the statement holds for k$<$n) in turning the product that goes from 0 to n-1 (in the first line of the right hand side of the solution) into $\frac{1}{2n!}$.

Comment: They used induction. Assume the result is true for $n-1$ and split off the factor for $i=n$. This gives you the product you have written on the right-hand side of your inequality. the product evaluates to $\frac{1}{(2n)!}$ by the induction hypothesis, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last step, $\displaystyle\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2i+1}\frac{1}{2i+2}$ has been replaced with $\dfrac{1}{(2(n-1)+2)!}$. This uses the inductive hypothesis, that $\displaystyle\prod_{i=0}^{k}\frac{1}{2i+1}\frac{1}{2i+2}=\dfrac{1}{(2k+2)!}$ is true for $k=n-1$. The variables $k$ and $n$ are used a bit differently than in your bullet list, but the proof strategy is the same: Prove the result for $k=0$, then show that for any $n>0$, the result holds for $k=n$ with the assumption that it is true for $k=n-1$.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks so much for the help! Do you know why they used k=n-1 instead of k=n+1? In general when should we use k=n-1 or k=n+1?

Comment: It doesn’t matter. What you need to be sure to do is prove a base case for $n$, and then be sure that for every larger value of $n$, the proposition can be deduced assuming it’s true for the previous value. So if you start with 0, be sure that however you use $k$ and $n$, the induction step has shown shows that the 0 case implies the 1 case, the 1 case implies the 2 case, etc. Sometimes the expressions are simpler if you show that the $k$ case implies the $k+1$ case for $k\ge0$; sometimes that the $j-1$ case implies the $j$ case for $j>0$, etc.